# Mapear array no retorno da função - PHP

Tags: php, apache, sintaxe, ini

Testando local (xampp), consigo no retorno da função mapear um array.
Exemplo:

```
<?php $res = $obj->Function()[0]['name']; ?>
```

E no servidor produção (hospedagens tipicas) está forma interpolada apresenta um erro do tipo "***Parse Error***";

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in *path/archive.php* on line 10

Como habilitar a disponibilidade de se trabalhar com essa sintaxe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse recurso que você quer se chama *array dereferencing*, e está disponível no PHP 5.4 para cima. De acordo com a [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

Isso significa que, algo que antes você fazia no PHP 5.3 para baixo:

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
echo $array[0]; // a
```

... pode ser simplificado no PHP 5.4 para cima:

```
echo ['a', 'b', 'c'][0]; // 1
```

Comment: Não conhecia o termo Array "dereferencing". Utilizando-o (inclusive aqui no SO) dá pra achar bastante conteúdo a respeito.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso

```
<?php $res = $obj->Function();
 echo $res[0]['name'];
?>
```

você vai pegar o retorno e instanciar na sua variável `$res` ai poderá manipular como quiser

Comment: Sim, isso foi o que utilizei para que funcionasse. Obrigado pela dica. Mas imaginei que a resposta fosse algo com o php.ini, ou alguma configuração do apache, ou coisa assim.